# Sql server database goes in Single User Mode while dropping it

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Our application uses multiple databases and these databases can be created by user through UI. Basically these databases are created after loading data from data files (ETL process)
We delete these databases when they are not required.
We use following statement to delete it -

`ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; Drop Database [{0}]`

Recently we started facing an issue where the database goes into Single User Mode but DB is not deleted and application stops working because only one connection can be active at a time in this mode. This issue occurs very **rarely** and not consistent at all. 
We don't have any clue on what is happening here.
If anybody has faced such an issues or what might be possible cause, please let me know.

We are using Sql Server 2008 R2

Regards,

Varun

Comment: Do you receive any errors concerning the `DROP DATABASE` command?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a race condition.  Between the time the database is set to single user and the time the DROP DATABASE command is issued if any other connection is successful then you will be unable to drop the database.  In a high volume situation this can be difficult to resolve.

The best bet is to set the database offline instead of putting it into SINGLE_USER.  Of course, in that case, you'll have to manually delete the database files.

Comment: Hi Jon, the possibility of this type of race condition is not possible because once a database goes into single user mode it can't accept or open any other connection. Moreover Alter database command runs in Autocommit mode so after this command is run, no other connection can be made to this database.

Comment: SINGLE_USER means ONE and only connection can be made. You cannot drop a database if you are connected to it, so the connection on which the DROP is run, by definition, cannot be the single connection allowed.   Therefore, anyone else connecting to the database between the time the ALTER completes and the time the DROP begins would have the effect of blocking your DROP operation. I have run into this problem myself on databases with regular activity. What you can do is run the ALTER while being connected to the database to grab the single connection, then add USE MASTER GO before the DROP.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a particularly large environment where there are at any given time 50+ machines which are hammering the database for connections. Even with delays set between connections the number of attempts being made is extremely large.

In our case, we handled this race condition by disabling the service account which was attempting to access the database before performing the single-user and drop commands which eliminated the issue for us.

If your system features a similar common service account, you may be able to implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The [Set a Database to Single-user Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-2017) documentation says:

> Prerequisites
>
> Before you set the database to SINGLE_USER, verify that the
>   AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option is set to OFF. When this option is
>   set to ON, the background thread that is used to update statistics
>   takes a connection against the database, and you will be unable to
>   access the database in single-user mode

Otherwise, the connection that sets the database to SINGLE_USER is supposed to immediately become the current and single user of that database, until you close that connection (notice that it can remain "in use", if your system is making use of connection pools that hold the connection open, but that should be unrelated to your problem).